# Probability of unfair dice

Tags: probability

this is a question from a BMAT practice textbook. I was wondering why the answer is C instead of B. The question is as below:

I have two identical unfair dice. The probability of rolling a 6 is twice as high as the probability of rolling any other number.
What is the probability that when one rolls both dice the total will be 12?

A. 0

B. 4/49

C. 1/9

D. 2/7

E. None of the above

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: There are two ways of reading "the probability of rolling any other number" means. But neither reading gets $1/9.$ It could mean that each of the other values are equally likely, and a $6$ is twice as likely as $1,$ twice as likely as $2,$ etc. Then $B$ is the right answer. The other reading, where a six is twice as likely as the combined probability of the other possibilities, gets $4/9.$

Comment: There is a $\frac{2}{7}$ chance of rolling a six on each die, each die is independent so the probability to roll both is $\frac{4}{49}$.

Comment: The remaining downvote should be removed because Teng clearly knows the correct answer but was told it was incorrect. This is not the same as merely posting a problem with no context or effort.

Answer (score 5):

The way the question is framed, I agree that the answer should be B, since twice as likely as any other number should imply probability of 6 is 2/7, then yielding probability of rolling 12 as 4/49.

To get 1/9, the question should have been phrased as "The probability of rolling a 6 is twice as high as the probability of rolling any other number **on a fair die**". Then 6 has a probability of 2/6=1/3, and so 12 becomes 1/9.

Comment: I'm impressed at the plausibly-backfilled explanation for the answer (+1)! But if that is indeed what they meant, this is among the worst-worded *and* worst-conceptualized questions I've ever heard. I think, perhaps optimistically, that "someone made a mistake" is the likelier answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Let the probability of rolling any one number, other than 6, be "x".  Then the probability of 6 is 2x. We must have 5x+ 2x= 7x= 1. x= 1/7 so the probability of rolling a 6 is 2/7.  The probability of rolling 2 "6"s is (2/7)(2/7)= 4/49, "B".